# How do I compare the value of x with the previous value?

Tags: python

how do I compare the values of x so that they are in increasing order

```
n = 5
i = 1
while i <= n:
    x = int(input())
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: save it for later use

Comment: `x = int(input())` then `temp = x`

Comment: At the bottom of the loop, save the value of `x` in another variable, perhaps called `previous_x`.  Then on the next loop, after you accept `x` as input, compare it to `previous_x`.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you want your program to do?  Do you want the program to print some message when a number is entered that is smaller than the previous value?  Do you want to print something when the number entered is larger than the previous value?  If you could show some sample input and your desired output, that would make it a lot clearer as to what you are hoping to accomplish here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
n = 5
i = 1
prev = float('-inf')
while i <= n:
    x = int(input())
    if x < prev:
        print(f'{x} is lesser than {prev}!')
        break
    prev = x
    i += 1
```

Comment: Glad to help you, if one of answers solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can only compare values to previous values, so you'll have to keep them around. Since you ask about "increasing order", it appears you want to collect all the inputs:

```
n = 5
i = 1
x = []
while i <= n:
    x += [int(input())]
    i = i + 1
x = sorted(x)
```

`x = []` sets up `x` as an empty list. `x += [int(input())]` does the same as your command, but instead of assigning the result directly to `x`, it puts it in a small list and adds that to the end of `x`. The final command just sorts the list in one go.

There's many ways to construct a list though. Instead of `x += [int(input())]`, you might prefer something like `x.append(int(input()))`. That's a matter of style, mostly.

Comment: Instead of `x += [int(input())]` would `x.append(int(input()))` be better?

Comment: @janzen Yes, it will be better since `append` has O(1) complexity unlike lists concatenation.

Comment: Given the simplicity of the question, I doubt that's a concern and I'd always recommend the more readable code - but you're definitely correct that `.append()` is the better performing option and should probably be preferred in many situations.

Answer (score -1):

While the previous answers are all correct, I prefer:

```
x = <some random value>
while i <= n:
    prev_x, x = x, int(input())
    ...
```

This makes it immediately clear that at the same time `x` is getting a new value, `prev_x` is getting its previous value.

Others' sensibilities may differ.

Comment: Your answer is not an answer to the question, but rather a comment on another answer and should probably have been posted as such.

Comment: @Grismar.  It isn't easy to do formatted multi-line code in comments, or I probably would have done so.  I was trying to do the simplest thing that would still be clear.

Comment: @FrankYellin If you feel the answer really needs it, you could propose an edit to the answer, either providing it as an alternative at the end, or even directly editing the code that was provided (although I'd probably reject that edit myself, as it's not directly relevant to the problem and just a style issue). Since you're concerned with style, providing a style comment as an answer, is poor SO-style...

Comment: @Grismar.  Ack.  Do you think I should delete?